# When is it correct to start a sentence with a participial phrase?

Tags: grammaticality, participles, sentence-starts

> Spending an hour in the beauty salon, Melissa got a facial with a steam mist.

Are there cases where starting with a participial phrase is not correct?

Comment: I think it's always correct as long as it is followed by a comma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's right as long as it's referring to the subject in the second part of the sentence. Else, it could be the case of a ['dangling modifer'](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/597/01/):

http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/597/01/

> Spending an hour in the beauty salon, Melissa got a facial with a steam mist: Right
>
> Spending an hour in the beauty salon, a facial with a steam mist was given to Melissa: Dangling Modifier

Comment: Is then "What is in the case of "raining all day, I decided to stay home" correct?

Comment: I don't think that would be correct as "raining all day" isn't referring to "I".